# ELV fixture + Maestro ELV dimmer does not dim, it simply switches

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, dimmer-switch

I just installed a Maestro ELV dimmer connected to a LED ELV-compatible fixture (WAC lighting).

The fixture does not dim however, it is 100% on at all dimmer settings and shuts off when the dimmer is off.

Any thoughts of the cause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Replace the dimmer

This sounds like you fried the dimmer's AC-chopping element to the point where it's simply a short circuit, while the internal mechanical switch is still able to turn the light on and off.

At this rate, I'd start by replacing the dimmer as the first port of call.

Comment: This could be true but also these dimmers can be configured to the wattage if the load. Perhaps they're configured to their highest setting, which is not a noticable amount at the load

Comment: @Matthew -- I don't believe they're configurable in the fashion you describe, perhaps you're mistaking the low-end or high-end trim adjustments?

Comment: You could be right, it has been a while since I used maestros